# Implement a method for specific type in a generic class in Java

Tags: java, generic-type-argument

I am trying to implement a generic class Distance to handle both Integer and LocalDateTime.(Physical distance and Time distance)
I want to create a method to show if a point is within this distance.
How can I implement different logic for Integer and LocalDateTime?

I have tried to create a class LocalDateTimeDistance that extends Distance, but I feel so wrong for doing this because Distance is already indicating a LocalDateTime distance, and I think change all Distance to LocalDateTimeDistance is so weird.

```java
public class Distance<T> {
    private T start
    private T end
}
```

```java
public class LocalDateTimeDistance<T extends LocalDateTime> extends Distance<T> {
    public boolean isPointWithinDistance(LocalDateTime ldt){
        LocalDateTime from = this.getFrom();
        LocalDateTime to = this.getTo();

        return (fromLocalDate.isBefore(ldt) || fromLocalDate.isEqual(ldt)) &&
               (toLocalDate.isAfter(ldt) || toLocalDate.isEqual(ldt));
    }
}
```

```java
public class IntegerDistance<T extends Integer> extends Distance<T> {
    public boolean isPointWithinDistance(Integer){
        //Logic for integer distance...
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Please explain what a `Distance` is intended to represent, and how that works with `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: `because Distance is already indicating a LocalDateTime distance` - no it's not.  It's capturing what a Distance is, which may be a LocalDateTime distance, or an Integer distance, or ....    More to the point, think very carefully what you mean by `change all Distance to LocalDateTimeDistance`.  In general, the only change you need make is changing when you call `new`;  All other references in your code should be happy to stay at just referring to your abstract `Distance` super class.

Comment: `public class LocalDateTimeDistance extends Distance<LocalDateTime>` and `public class IntegerDistance extends Distance<Integer>`

Comment: The java.time classes work very nice, but are a bit unwieldy. Instead of put upon that mass another API method (to learn), I would leave it to concrete non-generic code, and maybe later replace the code snippets with a generic method. Should it be often repeated, should it fit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I wouldn't necessarily recommend  using a generic class here. But to answer your question you can do this like so (within a single class):

```
public class Distance <T> {
    private T start;
    private T end;

    public boolean isPointWithinDistance(Object point){
        if (point.getClass().isAssignableFrom(LocalDateTime.class)){
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = (LocalDateTime) point;
            //do LocalDateTime logic
            //return resulting boolean
        }
        if (point.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)){
            Integer integer = (Integer) point;
            // do Integer related business logic
            // return resulting boolean
        }else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This method must be given either a LocalDateTime or Integer");
        }
    }
}
```

Just be careful, this kind of approach can become messy rather quickly. It would probably make more sense to keep all of this separate and distinct in the long run.

To do this I would recommend the following:

Make use of an interface:

```
public interface Distance <T> {
    public boolean isPointWithinDistance(T point);
}
```

and then implement that interface like so:

Integer:

```
public class IntegerDistance implements Distance<Integer> {
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public boolean isPointWithinDistance(Integer point){
        // do Integer related business logic
        // return resulting boolean
    }
}
```

LocalTimeDate:

```
public class LocalTimeDateDistance implements Distance<LocalDateTime> {
    private LocalDateTime start;
    private LocalDateTime end;

    public boolean isPointWithinDistance(LocalDateTime point){
        //do LocalDateTime logic
        //return resulting boolean
    }
}
```

The use of an interface gives you freedom in defining what is important (behavior wise) across the two and more flexibility (without the need to override) in writing different methods that are specific for the two implementations.

For example, perhaps you only want start and end to be positive numbers in the case of an integer. Perhaps you'll want a limit for the times that can be set for start and end in the case of date/time. You can easily set unique setters in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You almost there! You have a classic [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

You should implement calculation logic in two different classes and select only required one base in point type.

```
public final class Distance<T> {

    private final T start;
    private final T end;

}

public final class DistanceService {

    private final Predicate<LocalDateTime> dateTimeDistance = new Predicate<LocalDateTime>() {
        private final Distance<LocalDateTime> distance = new Distance<>(null, null);

        @Override
        public boolean test(LocalDateTime point) {
            return distance.getStart().isBefore(point) && point.isBefore(distance.getEnd());
        }
    };

    private final Predicate<Integer> integerDistance = new Predicate<Integer>() {
        private final Distance<Integer> distance = new Distance<>(100, 200);

        @Override
        public boolean test(Integer point) {
            return distance.getStart() <= point && point <= distance.getEnd();
        }
    };

    public boolean isPointWithinDistance(LocalDateTime point) {
        return dateTimeDistance.test(point);
    }

    public boolean isPointWithinDistance(int point) {
        return integerDistance.test(point);
    }
}
```

---

```
DistanceService service = new DistanceService();
boolean localDateTimeCheck = service.isPointWithinDistance((LocalDateTime)null);
boolean integerCheck = service.isPointWithinDistance(150);
```